# If $S \times \Bbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $T \times \Bbb{R}$ and $S$ is compact, can we conclude that $T$ is compact?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $S$ and $T$ are connected manifolds such that:
1) $S \times \mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $T \times \mathbb{R}$,
2) $S$ is compact.
can we conclude that $T$ is compact?

Comment: Maybe you should add to the question (edit it) to say that $S$ and $T$ are connected manifolds.

Comment: I have opened a new [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/385608/8087) for the general case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since $S$ and $T$ are locally connected, we may with out loss of generality assume, that $S$ and $T$ are connected. Now $S \times \mathbb R$ and hence $T \times \mathbb R$ have exactly two ends.

A connected and locally connected space is compact iff it has no ends. Suppose $T$ is not compact, then it would have at least one end. Now the product $T \times \mathbb R$ would have exactly one end, which is the desired contradiction.

Comment: what is an end?

Comment: @user76556: See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_%28topology%29).

Comment: @user76556: An end is basically a connected component at infinity. $\mathbb R$ has two of them (often denoted by $+\infty$ and $-\infty$). A space is compact iff it has no ends. The product of two connected spaces has one end if both factors have at least one end (draw a picture) and $n$ ends if one factor has zero and the other factor has $n$ ends.

Comment: I need this result for manifolds. and they are connected too.

Comment: I unaccepted it so that others don't get a wrong answer but i have the answer i was looking for. thank you.

Comment: @user76556: You should accept an answer not for the benefit of others, but to say that you are satisfied with it. Maybe you could edit your question, specifying that you were interested to the case of connected manifolds?

Comment: ok thanks for explaining